# How do you say "The sink drains slowly"?

Tags: formulation-idiomatique

I'm writing the owner of an airbnb that I stayed at whose kitchen sink drained slowly. How would you say this in French? I've searched google and wordreference forums but can't seem to find this.

Comment: I don't understand why the closure request was refused by moderators. French Language is not a translation service. Questions should show some research efforts, and at least say what they have found searching on the internet, google translate gives [L'évier s'écoule lentement](https://translate.google.fr/?hl=fr#en/fr/the%20sink%20drains%20slowly). The question could have said: "is google translate correct?". Other option for the OP would have been to ask on chat since he is a SE user with enough rep.

Comment: Apologies, I should have clarified the research I had done before posting. Google Translate actually gave me "L'évier draine lentement" and looking up the verbe drainer on Wordreference it didn't seem like the context was what I wanted. I'll include my previous research on future questions, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In French, we say "l'évier se vide lentement". It means that the sink is clogged. (l'évier est bouché)

Comment: You are saying that *l'évier se vide lentement* means ("it means") the sink is clogged. When it is clogged nothing goes through, it  does not drain at all...

Comment: It's interesting that your understanding of clogged is that the sink is completely blocked. I've always used clogged to say that something is obstructing the flow to a decent degree, but without indicating exactly what degree. If I wanted to indicate that water doesn't drain at all I'd use "blocked, stopped up, or clogged up". English is used so widely I'm sure there are regional differences.